How are Kerberos tickets managed and refreshed when using JDBC/HikariCP with a Keytab file on a Linux machine to connect to SQL Server
I'm managing several Java applications on a Linux machine that connect to a SQL Server database hosted on a Windows server using JDBC with HikariCP for connection pooling. These applications use Kerberos authentication with a Keytab file, and so far, I haven't encountered any connection issues.
The applications are a mix of Spring Boot and non-Spring Boot components (as we're gradually moving away from annotations based on the team's preferences). I've checked the Kerberos Key Distribution Center (KDC) configuration, and the ticket expiration is set to 10 hours. Despite having services running continuously for several days, I haven't experienced any issues. I initially thought this might be due to the HikariCP pool keeping the connections idle/connected, but I'm not entirely convinced that this explains the situation fully.
Given this, I'm concerned about what happens when Kerberos tickets expire, especially since the connections remain open for extended periods. Specifically, I would like to understand the following:
Who or what manages the Kerberos ticket renewal process in this setup?
Is it handled by com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule?
Is the JVM responsible for ticket renewal?
Is the SQL Driver or HikariCP involved in managing the Kerberos tickets?
How can I monitor or verify that the Kerberos tickets are being refreshed properly?
The Linux machine I’m working on does not have any Kerberos tools installed (e.g., klist, kinit), and installing them is not feasible in the short term due to an upcoming migration. Are there any alternative ways within the Java applications to monitor the ticket status?
Are there any best practices or configuration tips for ensuring that the Kerberos tickets are renewed seamlessly across all these applications?
Given the constraints of the environment, the mix of Spring Boot and non-Spring Boot components, and the long-running nature of these applications, any insights into how to monitor and manage Kerberos ticket expiration and renewal without relying on external Kerberos tools would be highly appreciated.

There's no provision in TDS protocol to re-auth anyway, so whatever you're worried about, you shouldn't. As long as you can create the initial connection that is :) I'm no kerberos expert, but you should probably look into the server for status, the client can't be expected to handle it?

SQL Server only checks credentials when you open a connection.  You can keep the connection open as long as you want.  So the details of the lifetime of the Kerberos ticket is normally irrelevant.

Equally it's not recommended to have connections open for longer than necessary because it puts extra load on the server.

If the application accepts a keytab (or a password) to obtain the initial ticket with on its own, then it would be reasonable to assume that the application – or the Kerberos library it uses – also handles ticket renewal (or re-acquiring with the same keytab) on its own, too.

This seems reasonable but is it just an assumption or a fact?
